# Themes in SharePoint 2013 Hosted App with Kendo Web UI

Tags: css

I plan to build new SharePoint 2013 Hosted App for SharePoint Store. I need for compliance use native SharePoint theme CSS classes. I do use Kendo Web UI / JavaScript library. How can I theme Kendo Web UI themes to be visible in SharePoint CSS themes ?